# Why is the space character not sorted in ASCII order?

Tags: python

Why is the space character treated differently when sorting?
Space is 32 in ACSII

```
a = "A"
b = "B"
c = "C"
d = " "
lst = [a, b, c, d]
lst.sort()
print(lst.sort()) # [' ', 'A', 'B', 'C']


a = "A"
b = "B"
c = "C"
d = " "
lst = [a, b, c, d]
lst.reverse()
print(lst) # [' ', 'C', 'B', 'A']
```

Answer (score 1):

It does. You just didn't call sort In your second case :-)

```
>>> sorted(['A', 'B', 'C', ' '], reverse=False)
[' ', 'A', 'B', 'C']

>>> sorted(['A', 'B', 'C', ' '], reverse=True)
['C', 'B', 'A', ' ']
```